# Namenode not accessible from outside Docker container

Tags: docker, hadoop, ssh, port

I dockerized a Hadoop application and I'm trying to access the namenode from outside the container for obvious reasons.

I exposed the port with the Dockerfile using:

```
EXPOSE 2122 9000
```

And I start the container with:

```
$ docker run -dit --rm --privileged --pid=host -p 2122:2122 -p 9000:9000 --name hnode ns/hnode
```

2122 beign the port I'm using for SSH. I already installed the SSH server, tried it and **I was able to connect via SSH from outside the container**.

I also added the option to Hadoop to use this SSH port instead with `ENV HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-p 2122"`.

---

Using the following core-site.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

When I try to telnet the 9000 from INSIDE the container, everything's fine:

```
[hadoop@1f5c7934fe45 hadoop]$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

   |��☼►☻↑      ")org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch*>Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 130♫: @☺Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And you clearly see that it's the namenode at the other end.

But when I try to telnet the 9000 port used by the namenode from inside the container using the host ip, I get:

```
[hadoop@1f5c7934fe45 hadoop]$ telnet 172.17.0.2 9000
Trying 172.17.0.2...
telnet: connect to address 172.17.0.2: Connection refused
```

Even though SSH is working:

```
[hadoop@1f5c7934fe45 hadoop]$ telnet 172.17.0.2 2122
Trying 172.17.0.2...
Connected to 172.17.0.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4

Protocol mismatch.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Why is SSH working but not Hadoop's namenode?

Comment: I added the ports of the HTTP interfaces of the Hadoop components and those are working fine from outside. There is only the namenode that won't speak to strangers. Also there is nothing in particular in the namenode logs.

Comment: I just changed the `core-site.xml` property using the external IP of the container. Telnet worked, that's promising.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just had to put the IP of the host in the core-site.xml instead of localhost:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://172.17.0.2:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

This way, I was able to telnet the namenode from inside with the outside route:

```
[hadoop@1f5c7934fe45 hadoop]$ telnet 172.17.0.2 9000
Trying 172.17.0.2...
Connected to 172.17.0.2.
Escape character is '^]'.

   |��☼►☻↑      ")org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch*>Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 100♫: @☺Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And even from outside:

```
λ curl 192.168.56.1:9000
It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon.
```

I know those are errors, but they confirm that the daemon answered and is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by editing `fs.default.name` and adding two more properties into the config file like this.

```xml
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Whether clients should use datanode hostnames when connecting to datanodes.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
    <value>172.17.0.2:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://172.17.0.2:9000</value>
</property>
```